# Line intersect Object

Tags: java, line, rectangles

```
Rectangle rEnemy = new Rectangle();
rEnemy.setBounds(0,0,40,40);

Rectangle rPlayer = new Rectangle();
rPlayer.setBounds(200,0,40,40);
```

my question: how can i make detection/intersection for rPlayer using something like "line" long for 100px?

example: rEnemy is at (0,0), rPlayer is at (100,0) and now rPlayer is intersecting line. there is a method rPlayer.intersect(rEnemy); but i what keep them 100px away from each other and get detection. of course i mean line which is aplicable for others positions of our rectangles because rPlayer and rEnemy are still in move.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, it sounds like you want to check if they are 100px away but intersecting on the x (or y) coordinate, not a 100px radius.

If you're trying to detect if they are within that bounds, you could merely make 1 or 2 rectangles that extend 100px in the x and y coordinates of either the enemy or player and check if the other piece intersects that.

But it would probably be better to just add 100px to the x coordinate of the enemy  and check if the player comes within that boundary, that way you aren't drawing more rectangles. I just mentioned that before because I thought it might be easier to visualize.

Comment: yes Im thinking about radius. cords X and Y of rectangles are changing all the time and i want see how long is "line" attached to each of them. its like i gave you line, we are moving all time and checking distans which is separating us by line.

Answer (score 0):

I just slove this by creating 3rd rect starting from rEnemy cords and making it width and height to rPlayer cords, then:

```
double calculate = Math.pow(Math.abs(rPlayer.x-rEnemy.x-Camera.posX), 2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(rEnemy.y-rPlayer.y+Camera.posY), 2);
int distance = (int)Math.sqrt(calculate);
```

variable distance is value of px which separate rPlayer and rEnemy at any position in shortest way.